# How can I run this function as a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a shell script, and I wish to do the following as part of a shell script without declaring a function. Basically, I would like to convert the following code into a shell script simply without declaring a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

function json2keyvalue {
   cat<<EOF | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)\t\(.value|tostring)")[]'
{
    "hello1": "world1",
    "testk": "testv"
}
EOF
}

while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value
do
    export "$key"="$value"
done < <(json2keyvalue)
```

into a shell script. I did the following,

```
values='{"hello1":"world1","hello1.world1.abc1":"hello2.world2.abc2","testk":"testv"}'
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value
do
    export "$key"="$value"
done < < (echo $values | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)\t\(.value|tostring)")[]')
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I run the shell script, it gives the error as follows, where file name is `abc.sh`.

```
./abc.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./abc.sh: line 6: `done < < (jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)\t\(.value|tostring)")[]' <<<"$values")'
```

The script takes a JSON like the following, and converts the key-values into environment variables.

```
{
    "hello1": "world1",
    "testk": "testv"
}
```

Comment: You have a stray space in the last line. Use `done < <(echo ...` instead of `done < < (echo ...`. Also, you should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$values"` instead of `echo $values`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s lastpipe
cat <<EOF | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)\t\(.value|tostring)")[]' | while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do export "$key"="$value"; done
{
    "hello1": "world1",
    "testk": "testv"
}
EOF
```

> `lastpipe`: If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell environment.

**Update**:

If variable `$values` contains valid json code, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s lastpipe
values='place valid json code here'
echo "$values" | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)\t\(.value|tostring)")[]' | while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do export "$key"="$value"; done
```

Comment: will I need to add `cat <<EOF` & also specify the JSON like you did? In my case, the JSON can be anything that is present in the variable `$values`.