# Variable is not being incremented in bash function

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
ql_remove_locks(){
  local pid="$$";
  declare -i count=0;
  ql_pid="$pid" ql_node_ls_all | while read line; do
    count=$((count+1));
    echo "count: $count";
    echo "deleting lock: $line";
    rm -rf "$line";
  done;
  echo "quicklock: $count lock(s) removed."
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
count: 1
deleting lock: /Users/alexamil/.quicklock/locks/a.lock
quicklock: 0 lock(s) removed.
```

I have tried so many things, still 0 always gets logged:

```
quicklock: 0 lock(s) removed.
```

Why is the count 0 instead of 1 in the echo statement?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48535917/3776858

Comment: See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: This is also [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in a pipeline are run in subshells. The `while` loop is in a subshell, with its own copies of variables, and modifying `$count` there doesn't propagate back to the parent shell.

You can switch the pipe to a redirection + process substitution to work around this.

```
while read line; do
  count=$((count+1))
  echo "count: $count"
  echo "deleting lock: $line"
  rm -rf "$line"
done < <(ql_pid="$pid" ql_node_ls_all)
```

NB: The semicolons are superfluous.